# how to allow traffic on specific IPs for a port in iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I want to restrict traffic for all IPs except 10.2.3.4 on port 5041

First I gave access to the IP on the port like so :

`iptables -A IN_public_allow -s 10.2.3.4 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5041 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT`

Then I restricted the access for all the IPs :

`iptables -A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5041 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP`

So theoretically, I should only have access to the port from IP 10.2.3.4, but that's not the case.
I am using ncat to test this, by using the -s option to change the source address :

```
ncat.exe -s 10.2.3.5 -zv  10.78.21.51 5041
libnsock mksock_bind_addr(): Bind to 10.2.3.5:0 failed (IOD #1): The requested address is not valid in its context.  (10049)
Ncat: Connected to :10.78.21.51:5041.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.12 seconds
```

So the command looks like it connected to the port from the IP 10.2.3.5 although it should not have.
I don't know what `libnsock mksock_bind_addr(): Bind to 10.2.3.5:0 failed` error means.
Please help , thanks.

EDIT : output of command `iptables -xvnL` as requested :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
642614522 702873881336 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  454146 27240797 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  392972 20241510 INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  392972 20241510 INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  392972 20241510 INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       3      120 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    4070   483366 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 326255 packets, 205303698 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
488899038 266093163662 OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 FWDI_public  all  --  bond1  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
       0        0 FWDI_public  all  --  bond0  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
       0        0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      bond1   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
       0        0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      bond0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
       0        0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public (3 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public (3 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    4307   492298 IN_public  all  --  bond1  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
  388631 19744052 IN_public  all  --  bond0  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
      34     5160 IN_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_public (3 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  392972 20241510 IN_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  392972 20241510 IN_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  392972 20241510 IN_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3179 ctstate NEW
    2477   145924 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5534 ctstate NEW
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5524 ctstate NEW
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8434 ctstate NEW
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5056 ctstate NEW
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3189 ctstate NEW
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 ctstate NEW
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 ctstate NEW
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       10.2.3.4        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5041 ctstate NEW
       5      260 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5041 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: We need to see your entire iptables rule set before we can comment. We need to see where the call to chain `IN_public_allow` is within the bigger context. In particular the INPUT chain. post the output from `sudo iptables -xvnL`.

Comment: I put the update you requested, it's pretty long, what should I be checking there ? pls

Comment: everything seems fine. The packets numbers don't add up, which I do not understand, unless somehow the `IN_public_allow` chain counts got zeroed independent of the others. I wanted to see the calls to chains and in what order. The packet counters show us that your DROP route was taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some checks, I found out that the iptables rules filter out the ip packets exactly how I wanted, the problem is that the netcat command `ncat.exe -s 10.2.3.5 -zv  10.78.21.51 5041`  doesn't actually change the source address as pe "-s" option , it still uses the default source address. Does any one know how telnet using a different source address ? is that possible ?

Comment: I have always used hping3 when I want to do testing by simulating (spoofing) a different source IP address.

Comment: is that for windows also ? because I need it there

Comment: I do not know...